# How to manually install a .deb file? (No apt or DPKG)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to install a package on an extremely underpowered piece of hardware. It is the Nintendo Wii. I only have 88 MB of RAM and it seems to not be enough for my PC to unzip the package. It is a major dependency of the LXDE desktop so it needs to be installed.

I extracted the deb and data on another PC and put all the files in their respective places on my Wii. Only problem is when I run `apt-get install -f` it doesn't recognize that it is installed. I added the entry to /var/lib/apt/extended_states but that didn't work either. Is there a text file that I can edit that Apt checks to know which packages are installed? The one that it uses to do `apt-get list --installed` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the files manually then the package manager will have no knowledge of it. I'm assuming that .deb was compressed with an unnecessarily high compression level for xz or similar? In any case, the best option is to repack it with a lower compression level or a different compressor so that the low-end hardware can deal with it.

You can simply run `dpkg-deb -R archive.deb out-dir`, then `dpkg-deb -Zgzip -b out-dir repacked.deb`, transfer the newly repacked.deb to the system and install normally with `dpkg -i repacked.deb`.